# Awk removing all blank lines in a script (not with command line)

Tags: awk, duplicates

I am converting a csv file into a pdf using LaTeX. My awk script looks like this:

```
BEGIN {printf "\\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{report}\n" \
"\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n"\
"\\usepackage[francais]{babel}\n"\
"\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n"\
"\\usepackage{hyperref}\n"\
"\\usepackage{textcomp}\n"\
"\\usepackage[left=1cm]{geometry}\n"\
..........
{print $1"\n" \
$2"\n" \
$3"\n" \
$4"\t"\
$5"\t" \
$6"\t" \
$7"\t" \
$8"\t" \
$9"\t" \
$10"\n""\\linebreak" \
......
$39"\t"\
$40;}

END {print "\\end{document}";}
```

I have found various flavors of commands to remove blank lines in the command line (awk 'NF', awk '$0!~/^$/ {print $0}') and tried to incorporate them at the end of the script with various combinations of BEGIN and END statements but nothing works.

Could anyone help? Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: can you ask a bit clearer. I didn't understand a question at all. Provide some simple example of csv that is processed incorrectly by your script and explain what exactly is incorrect, i.e. what would you want have as final result.

Comment: @Max: the csv is processed fine except that I have got blank lines after each record, before a \linebreak insertion and after \linebreak insertion. I need to remove those blank lines to process the .tex file to pdf correctly. Of course, if I run awk NF filename from the command line, it works fine. But the point is to have a clean file with a single script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `!/^$/` before this line `{print $1"\n" \`:

```
!/^$/ {print $1"\n" \
```

**Edit:**

Here's another approach:

```
BEGIN {
    ...
}
!/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {    # skip blank *input* lines
    output = $1"\n" \
             $2"\n" \
             ...
             $40
    # remove blank lines from *output*
    # it also removes trailing whitespace from each line
    gsub("([[:blank:]]*\n)+", "\n", output)
    print output
}
END {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it does not work. I have tried as you noted and also with curly braces before {print...}.

Comment: @Trying: Your script should have the general form `BEGIN { do-setup; print-headers} { per-line-processing } END { finalize; print-footers; do-cleanup }` (not necessarily all of those things). So the `BEGIN` clause should be closed before the line in my answer: `BEGIN { ... } !/^$/ {print ...`. If your blank lines have whitespace in them (i.e. they're not truly empty), then try `!/^[[:blank:]]$/` for the selector.

Comment: My begin statement goes like this: BEGIN {printf "\\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{report}\n" \ (.... bunch of stuff)"\\tableofcontents\n";
}

{FS="\t"}

{print $1"\n" \ (bunch of fields....)$40;}

END {print "\\end{document}";}

Comment: Sorry, got bogged down with the 5 mn edit : My begin statement goes like this: BEGIN {printf "\\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{report}\n" \ (.... bunch of stuff)"\\tableofcontents\n";
} 

{FS="\t"}

{print $1"\n" \ (bunch of fields....)$40;}

END {print "\\end{document}";}  I tried putting your code right after {FS="\t"} and before  {print $1"\n" \.... and it still does not work. I really have no clue since your code does look right. The output is all fine, with lots of blank lines before and after \linebreak lines.

Comment: @Trying: Setting `FS` should be done within the `BEGIN` clause. Your script should look like `BEGIN {printf "\\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{report}\n" \ (.... bunch of stuff)"\\tableofcontents\n"; FS="\t"} !/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {print $1"\n" \ (bunch of fields....)$40;} END {print "\\end{document}";}`. Note the removal of `} {`. Sorry, I forgot the asterisk in `!/^[[:blank:]]*$/` in my last comment.

Comment: @Trying: Something I didn't notice before is that if you have any empty *field* in your input, you'll probably get blank lines in your *output* since you're printing all those newlines. I thought you had blank lines in your input file that you're trying to get rid of. Which is the case?

Comment: @Dennis: I indeed have blank lines in my input file (duplicate fields removed to form chapters and such) so it is normal to have them in the output. I just thought I would remove them in the final script (being a newbie, I ended up with 3 scripts: #1 inserts the labels and such in the data; #2 removes duplicate fields (I think you gave that one to me a month ago or thereabouts!);#3 outputs with Latex headers and outputs records as one field --one long document!

Comment: @Dennis: if I insert FS="\t" within the BEGIN statement, it messes up the output. The problem, if it can be solved, is really to get rid off the blanks in the end (as would a command line awk NF would do). (But it is silly to go back to command line to get the final output).

Comment: @Trying: There shouldn't be any difference between setting `FS` in the `BEGIN` clause and setting it the way you have it (unless you're setting it to another value in another part of the script). It's just not usually necessary to set it each time a line is read. See my edited answer for another approach.

Comment: @Dennis: your script works... better. That is, it removes all blank lines except for... one at the end of the last field (ie, end of record?) --and that is not good enough for LaTeX!. I left FS="\t" there because in fact I set each field to a different value later in the script so as to present the data in "parts" (maybe I'll revise that and try to resort to better LaTeX scripting).

Comment: @Trying: Try changing the `print output` to `printf output`.

Comment: Wow! It works great. I can now produce a pdf and latex2html document in a jiffy! I can't thank you enough. Have a good evening. And thanks again!

Comment: @Trying: You may be interested in looking at [`csv2latex`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/csv2latex/).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks for the link. It seems csv2latex is for Mac and I am a Linux user. Also, the documentation is scant and I gathered it will process tables as tables in the output, where I want to process tables as paragraphs in a pdf and/or html format (I use latex2html at the end of the process --then my users either use the data as pdf or html whatever suits their fancy!). Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Trying: I believe you're correct about the tables. It sounds like it's not what you need. It is available for Linux, however (it's in the Ubuntu repository, for example).